# NVIDIA display driver files from different(incompatible) ver. of the driver have been detected

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

My pc seems to have encountered a headache of an error, everytime I open a program requiring my display drivers, this error pops up.

[image: Error encountered when opening filmora, adobe premiere, and other apps that use the display driver.]

And when I try to see the settings and navigate to the control panel, this error happens.

[image: Error encountered when trying to access the NVIDIA control panel.]

Here's my computer info:

- Windows Edition: Win 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1
- Rating: 3.3
- Processor: AMD Sempron(tm) 140 Processor 2.70 GHz
- Installed memory(RAM): 8.00 GB
- System Type: 64 bit OS
- Display adapter: NVIDIA GeForce 7025/ NVIDIA nForce 630a (Microsoft
  Corporation - WDDM)

Motherboard:

- http://www.emaxxtech.com/drivers/?wpfb_s=emx-mcp61d3&wpfb_list_page=1
  emx-mcp61d3-icafe

I've seen a couple of fixes and tried them but still unsuccessful in removing the said errors such as driver rollback, NVIDIA GeForce Experience(which doesnt show a thing - but the app runs and the interface is displayed, no data seen though) driver reinstall.

I also did what Sir @Tetsujin suggested. Uninstall, then install the driver from the link. But maaan, this error showed up.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks!

EDIT: The issue has been fixed. YEYY!!!
After the failed install above, I tried running filmora. to my surprise, it worked!

It seems the old drivers were really wrong, ohhhhhh!

But now I encountered a small problem. Now that I removed the driver, my screen became zoomed in, cropped and looks horrible. I tried playing with the resolution but none fit the bill.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried doing what it says & reinstalling the drivers? Last ever version supporting that card was from Feb 2015 - http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/82758/en-us

Comment: That...  I haven't done it yet. I was a bit scared to do so. Will create sys restore point, uninstall the driver and reinstall the driver from the given link. Many thanks, Sir Tetsujin!(Will come back here 1hr later, download speed is slow. Thank youuuu!)

Comment: Hi there Sir, I did the following steps but still wasn't able to fix it. Would kindly see my updated post? Thanks again! Edit: I tried runnning filmora after the failed install. It ran! Oh my gosh! It was that all along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed! For some reason, the drivers installed weren't right so I uninstalled it then installed a detector from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool